# Dynamically generating properties in a reactjs component's state

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have very large form, I would like to have a state that saves all of the user's input data, in different attributes named after the form.

So lets suppose I have a form with name, age and email. I want all of that to be saved in state called value. So once the form is filled I would have `this.state.value[name]`, `this.state.value[age]` and `this.state.value[email]`.

However this does not work, I get an error when I try to store the form's input data in that matter.

Here is the code for handleChange():

```
handleChange(e) {
     //this.setState({value[e.target.name]: e.target.value}); //does not work
     this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value}); //works!
}
```

So how could I store the values in from the forms under a state attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you do it like this:

```
const value = Object.assign({}, this.state.value)
value[e.target.name] = e.target.value
this.setState({ value })
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`value[e.target.name]` is not a valid key. What you are attempting is to perform an update of the states `value` property, for which I would recommend something like [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper).

In which case your update would look like:

`this.setState({value: update(this.state.value, {[e.target.name]: {$set: e.target.value})})`

Note that the use of [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create a copy as posted in another answer (+1) will achieve the same thing and is perfectly reasonable in this case. The immutability helper, however, is a useful tool to have for more complex updates.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to point out that `value` is not defined in that method, which could be why you get the error (you never specified the exact error).

You would typically store the values as they are updated.

`<input onChange={ e => this.setState({name: e.target.value}) />`

Then, when the form is submitted, you would have access to all of the values in the state object.

Comment: I think the op knows how to do this (see this works part of question) and is asking how to store them as keys in the same object as opposed to the root state